# Extend Angular service/factory to take an array of dates and an array of integers, and create an array with key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-services

I have a service/factory that takes an array of dates, and group it in an array of arrays `[[],[]]` according to ISO weeks. This feature works as expected.

But how can I extend the service/factory to take another array of values (just normal integer values), and **create a key-value pair of each date and value**. Still in the same output format of an array of arrays?

**This is my service/factory call:**

```
$scope.weeks = GroupDateRangeService.createArray(timeline_data, time_trend);
```

**The data that is passed to the service would look like this:**

```
timeline_data: ["2017-01-04","2017-01-05","2017-01-06","2017-01-07","2017-01-08","2017-01-09","2017-01-10","2017-01-11"]

time_trend: [566, 607, 430, 357, 277, 591, 711, 206]
```

**The result would look something like this:**

```
result: [["2017-01-04": 566,"2017-01-05": 607,"2017-01-06": 430,"2017-01-07": 357,"2017-01-08": 277], ["2017-01-09": 591,"2017-01-10": 711,"2017-01-11": 206]]
```

**This is my service/factory:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('portalDashboardApp')
        .factory('GroupDateRangeService', GroupDateRangeService);

    GroupDateRangeService.$inject = [];

    function GroupDateRangeService() {

        var service = {
            createArray: createArray,
        };

        return service;

        function createArray(data) {
            var arr = data.map(function (s) {
                var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
                return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;
            }).sort();
            return createGroupedArray(createGroupObject(arr));
        };

        function createGroupObject(arr) {

            var groupedObj = arr.reduce(function (result, value) {

                var b = value.split(':');

                if (!result[b[0]]) result[b[0]] = [];
                result[b[0]].push(b[1]);

                return result;

            }, {});

            return groupedObj;
        };

        function createGroupedArray(groupedObj) {

            // Grab arrays in order of week number. Sort keys to maintain order
            var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort().map(key=>groupedObj[key]);

            return groupedArray;
        }

        /* Helper to get the ISO week number of a date
        ** @param {Date} date to get week of
        ** @returns {Array} [year, weekNumber]
        */
        function getWeekNumber(d) {
            d = new Date(+d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
            var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
            return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
        }

        /* Parse ISO 8601 format date string to local date
        ** @param {string} s - string to parse like 2016-12-15
        ** @returns {Date}
        */
        function parseISOLocal(s) {
            var b = s.split(/\D/);
            return new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]);
        }
    }

})();
```

I would appreciate your guidance!

Comment: So you're just looking for a routine that would merge your two arrays?

Comment: My service only takes the date at this time. i would like to expand the functionality, and pass an integer value array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result cannot look like that, an array cannot have key-value pairs. It will have to be an array of array of objects. If you refactor your function to take a second argument you can do the following :

```
function createArray(data, optionalTimeTrend) {
    var arr = data.map(function (s) {
        var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
        return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;
    }).sort();
    var results = createGroupedArray(createGroupObject(arr));
    if (optionalTimeTrend && optionalTimeTrend.length === data.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[i] = results[i].map(function (date, index) {
                var obj = {};
                obj[date] = optionalTimeTrend[index];
                return obj;
            });
        }
    }
    return results;
};
```

Your results should look like this then :

```
result: [[{"2017-01-04": 566},{"2017-01-05": 607},{"2017-01-06": 430},{"2017-01-07": 357},{"2017-01-08": 277}], [{"2017-01-09": 591},{"2017-01-10": 711},{"2017-01-11": 206}]]
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you for the clarification and help. I will test it out and revert. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Think this is your merge routine here (updated to show how to use internal vs. provided arrays, and how to switch processing instructions):

```
// These arrays were already made by your service
let premadeKeys = [ 'pre', 'made', 'keys' ];
let premadeVals = [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ];

// Formatrules is a naive way to switch how you want it processed, could be any enum etc.
function mergeArrays ( keys = premadeKeys, values = premadeVals, formatRules = 0 ) {
   switch ( formatRules ) {
        case 0:
            return keys.map ( ( d, i ) => {
                let obj = {};
                obj [ d ] = values [ i ];
                return obj;
            } ); 
        case 1:
            return keys.map ( ( d, i ) => {
                let obj = {};
                obj [ d ] = values [ i ] + '_TAIL_' + i;
                return obj;
            } );    

   }
}

let arr1 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
let arr2 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
// provided arrays
console.log ( mergeArrays ( arr1, arr2 ) );
console.log ( mergeArrays ( arr1, arr2, 1 ) );
// pre made arrays
console.log ( mergeArrays ( ) );
console.log ( mergeArrays ( undefined, undefined, 1 ) );
```

Comment: Thank  you. It looks straight forward. But how can I add this to my service, and pass the 2 values to my service and return the results? My issue is the service creates the array of arrays of ISO weeks, and it is at this time that the key-value pairs will most probably have to be created.

Comment: Hmm, a little unclear here: when you inject your service, you can access methods and so on. You can add this method to your service, and from anything that you injected the service into, you can just call getMergedArrays ( ), it grabs the two arrays your service is already holding, runs them through this, and returns the result, such that any component you've injected the service into just has to call "this.mySvc.getMergedArrays().

Comment: True, but I think I am unclear on this; my service currently takes an array of dates and create an array of arrays grouped by ISO weeks. Would it be this array of arrays that I will pass to `mergeArrays`, or does this simply take my 2 arrays and merge them? If so, how will my other functionality in the service that creates the array of ISO weeks handle this new format etc.?

Comment: Does ISO actually have anything to do with it (from what I can see I don't think so, it doesn't matter what the arrays hold). 

You can either submit two arrays to the function from anywhere, or just call the function and if the arrays are blank, it will use the defaults (the ones the service has already built, will update a bit to demo). You can provide different map functions depending on how you want the new array assembled (I'll add a bit for this too).

Comment: Note that I read another answer and am assuming you know that in order for you to associate a key with a value, you have to return an array of objects, e.g. [ { key : val }, { key : val } ]. Any code you wrote that just accesses an array index will have to be updated to reflect that the myArr [ n ] value is now an object, so you access the val like myArr [ n ].keyname.